# How can i send get request using guzzle laravel pacakge with id

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send an API request

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction', [
            'id' => '18a20dbc34082451143c03ac54a2f24d06494d51e68f8fb1211ca0b63a53f37d'
        ]);
```

It's working in Postman and i get data properly, but don't working in Laravel project.

Comment: What does "_but don't working_" mean? Empty result? Result from the wrong id?

Comment: Client error: `GET https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "EOF" }

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Did you try `https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction?id=18a20dbc34082451143c03ac54a2f24d06494d51e68f8fb1211ca0b63a53f37d` as url?

Comment: Thank you solved

Comment: You could also use `$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction', ['query' => ['id' => '18a20dbc34082451143c03ac54a2f24d06494d51e68f8fb1211ca0b63a53f37d']]);`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code as [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters)

```php
<?php
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://domain/etc', [
    'query' => ['id' => '...']
]);
```